# How to know if there are any related task to the account?

Tags: apex, batch

I am trying to get the account where there is no task.AssignedTo = Account.OwnerId. I have written the
logic. But it looks like I can get it more easily. How can I optimize my batch? Any help will be appreciated.

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) 
{
    DateTime pastDatetime = DateTime.now().addDays(-Integer.valueOf(10));
    String  query =  'SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, WhatId, OwnerId, ActivityDate FROM ActivityHistories )';
            query+=  ' FROM Account WHERE mydate__c> :pastDatetime'   ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 10';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}
 
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope) 
{
    
    List<ActivityHistory> accntHistoryList= new List<ActivityHistory>();
    //Adding list of activity history based on queried data
    for(Account ob:scope){
        accntHistoryList.addall(ob.ActivityHistories);
    }

    Map<Id,List<Id>> mapOfAccountIdOwnerId = new Map<Id,List<Id>>(); 
    for(ActivityHistory actHistoryList : accntHistoryList){

        if(!mapOfAccountIdOwnerId.containsKey(actHistoryList.accountId)){
            mapOfAccountIdOwnerId.put(actHistoryList.accountId,new List<Id>{actHistoryList.ownerId});   
        }else{
            List<Id> updateOwner = mapOfAccountIdOwnerId.get(actHistoryList.accountId);
            if(!updateOwner.contains(actHistoryList.ownerId)){
                updateOwner.add(actHistoryList.ownerId); 
                mapOfAccountIdOwnerId.put(actHistoryList.accountId,updateOwner);   
            }
        }
    }
    //Here I am updating the account where task.ownerid not equal to acccount ownerId
    List<Account> acctoUpdate = new List<Account>();
    for(Account ob:scope){
        if(mapOfAccountIdOwnerId.containsKey(ob.Id) && !mapOfAccountIdOwnerId.get(ob.Id).contains(ob.ownerId)){
            ob.Normalize__c = null;
            acctoUpdate.add(ob);
        }
    }
    UPDATE acctoUpdate;
}
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{

}
```

**Usecase is**: If the account does not have any related Tasks where OwnerId = Account.OwnerId, i need to set Normalize__c = null

Can I know if there is any alternative way which makes code more optimized. Please suggest.

Comment: Do you need accounts that `aren't linked to any task` or `account owners` which are not assigned to the task?

Comment: @SachinHooda If the account does not have any related Tasks where OwnerId = Account.OwnerId i need to set Normalize__c = null;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an ideal use case for a Set. Here's an optimized version to get you started:

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator([
        SELECT OwnerId FROM Account
    ]);
}
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Account[] scope) {
    // Track Account.OwnerId + Task.OwnerId
    Set<Id[]> taskOwnerByAccount = new Set<Id[]>();
    // OwnerIds we are interested in
    Set<Id> accountOwnerIds = new Set<Id>();
    // Records to Update
    Account[] recordsToUpdate = new Account[0];
    // Get OwnerIds
    for(Account record: scope) {
        accountOwnerIds.add(record.OwnerId);
    }
    // Use AggregateResult to quickly find AccountOwnerId/TaskOwnerId pairs
    for(AggregateResult result: [
        SELECT AccountId AccountId, OwnerId OwnerId 
        FROM Task 
        WHERE   Account.MyDate__c > :DateTime.now().addDays(-10)
                AccountId = :scope AND 
                OwnerId = :accountOwnerIds
    ]) {
        taskOwnerByAccount.add(
            new Id[] { 
                (Id)result.get('AccountId'), 
                (Id)result.get('OwnerId')
            }
        );
    }
    for(Account record: scope) {
        // Check to see if set contains this account/owner pair
        if(!taskOwnerByAccount.contains(new Id[] { record.Id, record.OwnerId })) {
            record.Normalize__c = null;
            recordsToUpdate.add(record);
        }
    }
    update recordsToUpdate;
}
```